# Is $n^{1/10}$ a cauchy sequence?

Tags: convergence-divergence

So, I stuck at a step to prove that $n^{1/10}$ is not a cauchy sequence. 
So, $$|y_n - y_m| = |n^{1/10} - m^{1/10}|$$

So, now how is the next step to show, that it is not a cauchy sequence?

Comment: just apply the definition, what has to hold for $n,m,\varepsilon$?

Comment: e > 0, all n,m are natural numbers

Comment: Assuming you're using the standard metric on the line, a sequence is Cauchy if and only if it converges. Does $\sqrt[10]{n}$ converge?

Comment: No not really, but I just need the correct mathematical prove

Comment: Hint: Compute $|y_n-y_m|$ for $n=k^{10}$ and $m=(k+1)^{10}$, when $k\to\infty$.

Comment: @Maxim You *cannot* prove that the sequence is Cauchy (under the standard metric), because it isn't to begin with.

Comment: I´m sorry, I have falsely written. I want to show that is NOT a cauchy sequence. Sorry for the disturbing

Comment: If you want something direct, note that $x^{1/10}>2$ for $x>1024$, so $(2n)^{1/10}-n^{1/10}>n^{1/10}>1$ for all $n>1024$.

Comment: Cauchy $\implies$ bounded.